# What is the correct way to define an alias to `after` in rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, metaprogramming

Normally the `before` and `after` hooks are assumed to be "initializing" and "cleanup" code respectively. They are supposed to happen "outside of the tests themselves".

I find myself in a situation in which I want to use `after` as the last step of all the tests in a context. But since `after` is usually meant to be "cleanup", I am afraid that my tests won't be very explicit. Here's a sample:

```
describe "when removing" do
  let!(:request) do
    stub_request(:delete, "http://localhost:4567/containers/#{container.id}").
    to_return(status: 200)
  end

  # returns an http response
  subject { client.remove(container.id) }

  it { should be }
  it { should include('id' => container.id) }

  after { expect(request).to have_been_made }
end
```

I would like to rename that last `after` to something more explicit, like `invariant`, to indicate that it is part of the test. I have tried doing this on my spec helper:

```
# spec_helper.rb

Rspec.configure do |c|
...
end

RSpec::Core::Hooks.class_eval do
 alias_method :invariant, :after
end
```

requiring `spec_helper` does not seem to throw any errors, but when I run the tests replacing `after` with `invariant` I get `"undefined method 'invariant' for #<Class:0x007f9872b46588> (NoMethodError)"` when running the tests.

Comment: Any updates on this? Considering opening an issue (and/or PR) with RSpec to add this. Configuration options were added to alias example groups (`describe`/`context` blocks) and examples (`it` blocks), so this seems consistent.

Comment: @vergenzt I have no updates on this, sorry. As my answer indicates, I just ended up using `after`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no easy way to do this, just use `before`/`after`